# Why does my clock widget use a lot of RAM after a while?

Tags: android, bitmap, widget, ram

I created a clock widget that is updated from service (via broadcast receiver) every minute but after some hours it takes about 600mb of RAM.

The widget draws a bitmap every minute  with some features and shows it by a simple `ImageView`.

At the beginning the widget occupies only a few kb of ram, but after a few minutes it takes hundreds of mb. There is a way to clear RAM before create the new bitmap?

This is a part of widget code:

```
public class Widget_01_Clock extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

Bitmap clock = WidgetPaint.getClockBitmap();


RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.w_01_clock);

updateViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.w_01_clock, clock);
}
}
```

Comment: Show us your code. You have a memory leak.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions here too about Bitmap recycling and re-use and memory management. It can get tricky. Search around for "bitmap recycle" or such (if you aren't already doing so).

Comment: Thanks guys. I edit and write a part of my code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the is that every minute you load a new bitmap into your memory. 
So your solution should be one of the following:

1. as already suggested recycle your used bitmap, for future use of this block of memory for next bitmaps.
2. work with really small images (thumbnails) that wont take so much space, and wont cause you an `OutOfMemory` exception.

Personally I think you should do both, here is a code to create a thumbnail version of your image file:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path,
int reqWidth, int reqHeight) { // BEST QUALITY MATCH

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight) {
    inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
}

int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
    //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger    SampSize..
    inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
}


options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I create a new bitmap in separate processes.
If I use bitmap.recycle() bitmap is null.

Comment: what heppens when you put clock.recycle(); after the line of RemoteViews?

Comment: Emill Adz I tried put clock.recycle(); after the line of RemoteViews but the result is always the same. After many time when I click on "Show Cache Processes" in settings the RAM taken is very large (about 100mb after 10 min).

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat that you are in, and I MAY have found a solution to keep it somewhat low. After lots of searching and failed results, I can get my clock widget (which has a background image up to 800x800, an overflow-menu image, time, and date -- all bitmaps) to normally go no higher than 45mb; if the user doesn't mess with the widget's settings and customization, it can sometimes stay below 20mb -- as I'm writing this, it's dropped to ~11MB. (then after messing with the customization, jumped to 41MB, and is now sitting at less than 10MB for about an hour now)

Your question says your clock has some features; I'm assuming this is an image of some sort? Well, I noticed with mine that, every minute, on every update, I redrew everything (background, menu, time, and date). I managed to break that in to three parts: menu (has to be separate for the pending intent), background + date (only gets updated when I have `UPDATE` intent or `TIME CHANGED`), and the time. I use a `SparseArray` in my Static class to hold the background + date bitmap, then when I'm only updating the time, I call that bitmap so I don't have to recreate it. Then when I set my remote views, I have something similar to this.

```
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_consolidated, sparseArrayOfBitmaps.get(widgetNumber);
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_time, functionToReturnTimeBitmap(arguments));
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_overflow, functionToReturnMenuBitmap(arguments));
```

You might need to do something similar. It won't always keep the memory low (at least for me), but it does seem help.